# Using pypa's build on a python project leads to a generic "none-any.whl" wheel, but the package has OS-specific binaries (cython)

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, pypi, python-packaging

I am trying to build a package for distribution which has cython code that I would like to compile into binaries before uploading to PyPI. To do this I am using pypa's `build`,

`python -m build`

in the project's root directory. This cythonizes the code and generates the binaries for my system then creates the sdist and wheel in the `dist` directory. However, the wheel is named "--py3-none-any.whl". When I unzip the `.whl` I do find the appropriate binaries stored,
(e.g., `cycode.cp39-win_amd64.pyd`). The problem is I plan to run this in a GitHub workflow where binaries are built for multiple python versions and operating systems. That workflow works fine but overwrites (or causes a duplicate version error) when uploading to PyPI since all of the wheels from the various OS share the same name. Then if I install from PyPI on another OS I get "module can't be found" errors since the binaries for that OS are not there and, since it was a wheel, the installation did not re-compile the cython files.

I am working with 64-bit Windows, MacOS, and Ubuntu. Python versions 3.8-3.10. And a small set of other packages which are listed below.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

*Simplified Package*

```
Tests\
Project\
    __init__.py
    pycode.py
    cymod\
        __init__.py
        _cycode.pyx
_build.py
pyproject.toml
```

*pyproject.toml*

```ini
[project]
name='Project'
version = '0.1.0'
description = 'My Project'
authors = ...
requires-python = ...
dependencies = ...

[build-system]
requires = [
    'setuptools>=64.0.0',
    'numpy>=1.22',
    'cython>=0.29.30',
    'wheel>=0.38'
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools]
py-modules = ["_build"]
include-package-data = true
packages = ["Project",
            "Project.cymod"]

[tool.setuptools.cmdclass]
build_py = "_build._build_cy"
```

*_build.py*

```py
import os
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py as _build_py


class _build_cy(_build_py):

    def run(self):
        self.run_command("build_ext")
        return super().run()

    def initialize_options(self):
        super().initialize_options()
        import numpy as np
        from Cython.Build import cythonize
        print('!-- Cythonizing')
        if self.distribution.ext_modules == None:
            self.distribution.ext_modules = []

        # Add to ext_modules list
        self.distribution.ext_modules.append(
                Extension(
                        'Project.cymod.cycode',
                        sources=[os.path.join('Project', 'cymod', '_cycode.pyx')],
                        include_dirs=[os.path.join('Project', 'cymod'), np.get_include()]
                        )
                )

        # Add cythonize ext_modules
        self.distribution.ext_modules = cythonize(
                self.distribution.ext_modules,
                compiler_directives={'language_level': "3"},
                include_path=['.', np.get_include()]
                )
        print('!-- Finished Cythonizing')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by adding in a nearly empty setup.py file into the root directory alongside pyproject.toml. The rest of the files are the same as the original post.

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import Extension, setup

extensions = [
    Extension(
       'Project.cymod.cycode',
       sources=[os.path.join('Project', 'cymod', '_cycode.pyx')],
       include_dirs=[os.path.join('Project', 'cymod'), np.get_include()]
       )
    ]


setup(
    ext_modules=extensions
)
```

OS-specific wheels are now being built rather than broken generics. It looks like this is a limitation of pyproject.toml at the moment.